# What steps do I need to take to install a local copy of a live website?

Tags: sql

I need to create a local copy of a live site for development purposes.

The live site is 30GB+ in size and so I don't want to download all of the uploaded media.

I have copied all but the uploads directory to my development machine.

I have also made a copy of the database:

```
mysqldump -u root -p live_db > db.wp__backup.sql
```

And from here on, I'm stuck.

I have the WP CLI installed. I have tried these steps:

```
> wp db create
> wp db import db.wp__backup.sql
```

But when I start WP, I'm taken to the new installation page and a fresh installation is created without any of the data from the database.

Given that I have a copy of the database and the site directory itself, how do I create a local copy of a WP website?

Answer (score 0):

wp-cli makes use of your `wp-config.php` credentials to connect to the db, so the fact that you are getting the install screen, and not getting any errors (I assume) when running wp-cli commands says that you seem to have it configured correctly. My only thought would be that your `$table_prefix` value doesn't match the tables you've imported.